# Docker: Add Linux korn Shell to an existing container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, command, ksh

I’m quite new to docker and I want to add the Linux Korn Shell to an existing Container.

I used this command :

```
  yum install ksh
```

I get these errors:

```
    fastesmirror
    Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
    * epel: fedora-archive.ip-connect.vn.ua
    * epel-debuginfo: fedora-archive.mirror.liquidtelecom.com
    * epel-source: fedora-archive.mirror.liquidtelecom.com
    Setting up Install Process
    No package ksh available.
    Nothing to do
```

Can someone help me to install ksh ?

Thank you !

PS: it's a Ubuntu 8.3.0

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu, you need to use apt-get instead of yum to install any package. So to install ksh, you need to use the command `apt-get -y install ksh`. Here's my Dockerfile-

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get -qqy update && apt-get dist-upgrade -qqy && apt-get -y install ksh
```

And here's the output from my container showing that ksh was indeed installed-

```
root@qa6:~/amitp/p1# docker run -it 948453249b61 bash
root@ea237be38b71:/# ksh
# echo $0
ksh
#
```

**Update**:
The above was for a container with ksh installed when container image is built. If you have any existing Ubuntu container running, use a similar command as shown below to install ksh-

```
root@qa6:~/amitp/p1# docker run -it 72300a873c2c bash
root@5c844bb2b7ad:/# ksh
bash: ksh: command not found
root@5c844bb2b7ad:/# apt-get -qqy update && apt-get dist-upgrade -qqy && apt-get -y install ksh
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  binfmt-support libpipeline1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  binfmt-support ksh libpipeline1
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 921 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3665 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libpipeline1 amd64 1.5.0-1 [25.3 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 binfmt-support amd64 2.1.8-2 [51.6 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 ksh amd64 93u+20120801-3.1ubuntu1 [844 kB]
Fetched 921 kB in 1s (793 kB/s)
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Selecting previously unselected package libpipeline1:amd64.
(Reading database ... 4046 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpipeline1_1.5.0-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpipeline1:amd64 (1.5.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package binfmt-support.
Preparing to unpack .../binfmt-support_2.1.8-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking binfmt-support (2.1.8-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package ksh.
Preparing to unpack .../ksh_93u+20120801-3.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ksh (93u+20120801-3.1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libpipeline1:amd64 (1.5.0-1) ...
Setting up binfmt-support (2.1.8-2) ...
update-binfmts: warning: Couldn't load the binfmt_misc module.
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.
Setting up ksh (93u+20120801-3.1ubuntu1) ...
update-alternatives: using /bin/ksh93 to provide /bin/ksh (ksh) in auto mode
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/ksh.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/ksh93.1.gz (of link group ksh) doesn't exist
update-binfmts: warning: Couldn't load the binfmt_misc module.
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
root@5c844bb2b7ad:/# ksh
#
```

Comment: bash: apt-get; command not found. I type cat /proc/version and the version is : Linux version 5.0.0-38-generic (buildd@...) (gcc version 8.3.0 (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6u .....)

Comment: Can you get the outputs of `cat /etc/centos-release`, `cat /etc/issue` and `lsb_release -a`?

Comment: For cat /etc/issue I get  Centos release 5.11 (final) Kernel \r on an \m

Comment: Your original question mentioned Ubuntu 8.3.0 hence all the confusion , it's actually CentOS. Will try to find a solution for you.

Comment: Thank you for your help waiting for your comment